# Autofilter Column data one by one using buttons

Tags: function, excel, filter, vba

I have a some filtered data in a column that I would like to see for one value at a time by a macro. so far I have got up to the code below but it filters out when I manually select a value from the column. Is it possible that all the values get picked up by a macro function and when I run that it populates data one by one.

```
Sub Macro1() 

Columns("C:C").Select

ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table_Query1_added_columns2").Range.AutoFilter Field _ :=3, Criteria1:="101"

ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table_Query1_added_columns2").Range.AutoFilter Field _ :=3, Criteria1:="102"

ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table_Query1_added_columns2").Range.AutoFilter Field _ :=3, Criteria1:="103"

End Sub
```

Comment: `Field _ :=3` isn't a valid format for passing a parameter. Try `Field:=3` for starters

Comment: Sorry, it's a typo in code paste. actual code was written with Field:=3 and no errors.

Comment: I'm not sure what _but it filters out when I manually select a value from the column_ means. Also, the way your code is written, you'll set the auto-filter 3 times & leave it on the 3rd setting. Unless your data set is massive, it will likely happen fast enough that you won't see the first 2 setting changes.

Comment: your comment is correct. it leaves only the last one. I would like to see one at  a time(without time interval function) on a mouse button click. Requirement is to filter values on column 3 and one by one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (off the top of my head)

```
Sub Macro1() 
Static Filter as Integer

Columns("C:C").Select

if Filter = 0 then
  ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table_Query1_added_columns2").Range.AutoFilter _
            Field:=3, Criteria1:="102"
  Filter = 1
ElseIf Filter = 1 then
  ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table_Query1_added_columns2").Range.AutoFilter _
            Field:=3, Criteria1:="103"
  Filter = 2
Else
  ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table_Query1_added_columns2").Range.AutoFilter _
            Field:=3, Criteria1:="101"
  Filter = 0
End Sub
```

By declaring a variable `Static` its value remains set while the workbook is open. When you first click your button, the value of `Filter` will be initialized to `0`, the appropriate `.AutoFilter` set, and the value of `Filter` incremented.

The next time you click the button, the value of `Filter` will *still* be `1`, so the next `.AutoFilter` will be set & `Filter` will increment again.

When you click the button again, the next `.AutoFilter` will be set, and `Filter` will be reset to `0`, ready to select the first `.AutoFilter` criteria.

Comment: Thanks, 'Freeman' for replying on it. Only thing that lacks here for one final step here is I can't mention the Criteria1,2,3 fields in the code as the values for Col C get updated every time. when this happens code stops working. If possible, can a macro in the code auto capture all values(or filtered values) in Col C, and then working on the same code logic. functionality of button clicks stays limited here as the values for Col C criteria field have to be mentioned in current code. Thanks for time and efforts put in. !

Comment: Do a google search on how to pull unique values from a column (there are lots of examples - I'd have to, don't remember off the top of my head). Then, pull the uniques to a separate sheet. You can then modify the provided block of code to loop through your unique list instead of a hard-coded list. If you run into issues with that, create a new question posting your code and the specific issue you've hit. SO is very much a 1-question/1-answer setup, and extending it in comments breaks all the paradigms.

Comment: Yeah, I had a thought over it copying to another, but that's not a  good in approach setup rather then grabbing direct from the column. no worries - another will be created. thanks.

Comment: I suggested that because there is a nifty way of pulling unique values from a column using a built-in Excel function, and that would save writing your own code to do so. It may work for you, you may decide to roll your own.